# Moving an image icon within a JToggleButton?

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, jtogglebutton

Here's a  [picture of part of my interface.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKE5q.png) The image is circular with a transparent background but it doesn't center properly within the button. I was wondering if I could manually move it into position.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a JToggleButton and then set the icon of the button to the image you are using

```
  JToggleButton button = new JToggleButton(new ImageIcon("path to image"));
```

that should create the button, and put the image into the center of the button.

Hope that helps!